# How to pull an item from an array

Tags: python

I'm trying to pull out the number 28295 and apply it to another variable

```py
response = {u'sensors': [{u'objid_raw': 28295, u'objid': 28295}], u'treesize': 1, u'prtg-version': u'21.3.71.1416'}

objid = response['sensors'][0]?
```

Comment: `response['sensors'][0]['objid_raw']`?

Comment: `response['sensors'][0]['objid']`

Comment: What types of response former you making

Comment: Which key are you interested in? objid_raw, objid?

Answer (score 1):

Since I could see 2 keys with the value 28295, here is my generic anwser

```
for i in response['sensors']:
  print(i['objid_raw'],i['objid'])
```

Comment: let me know if this is the response you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

Let's do this step-by-step:

```py
response = {u'sensors': [{u'objid_raw': 28295, u'objid': 28295}], u'treesize': 1, u'prtg-version': u'21.3.71.1416'}

# First you get the list under 'sensors'
sensors = response['sensors'] # [{u'objid_raw': 28295, u'objid': 28295}]

# sensors is a list now and you want its first entry
entry = sensors[0] # {u'objid_raw': 28295, u'objid': 28295}

# entry now is a dict with the values you need, just extract either of those
objid = entry['objid'] # 28295

# it has the value you want
```

Or shorter as multiple people already mentioned:

```py
objid = response['sensors'][0]['objid'] # 28295
```

Comment: I"m getting an error of 'instancemethod' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

I feel like it's having an issue with sensors = responseJSON[u'sensors'] and the fact that sensors in the brackets is a string, but the "u" falls outside of it. Trying to wrap the whole thing as a string produces the same error.

sensors = responseJSON["u'sensors'"]

Comment: @cs-tech There are no methods defined here, so think you have some other issue

Comment: I see what you're saying. I'm trying to print the result of objid, so the print(objid()) would be the method erroring?

Comment: I made a mistake @cs-tech, you need to remove `u`. The post was edited to fix that.

Comment: @cs-tech Why are you calling `objid`? In the example, it's just an `int` so you're effectively saying `print(28295())` or `28295()`. Just use `print(objid)`.

Comment: I finally found the issue! I'm using requests, and when I was passing the response.JSON() into a variable, I was missing the (). That was the error from the method!